# How does Python store datetime internally?

Tags: python, c, datetime, memory, cpython

I found [`_datetimemodule.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_datetimemodule.c#L6072) which seems to be the right file, but I need a bit of help as C is not my strength.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import sys
>>> d = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> sys.getsizeof(d)
48
>>> d = datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 123)
>>> sys.getsizeof(d)
48
```

So a timezone-unaware datetime object nees 48 Bytes. Looking at the `PyDateTime_DateTimeType`, it seems to be a `PyDateTime_DateType` and a `PyDateTime_TimeType`. Maybe also `_PyDateTime_BaseTime`?

From looking at the code, I have the impression that one component is stored for each field in `YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:ss`, meaning:

- Year: e.g. int (e.g `int16_t` would be 16 bit)
- Month: e.g `int8_t`
- day: e.g. `int8_t`
- Hour: e.g. `int8_t`
- Minute: e.g. `int8_t`
- Second: e.g. `int8_t`
- Microsecond: e.g. `uint16_t`

But that would be 2*16 + 5 * 8 = 72 Bit = 9 Byte and not 48 Byte as Python tells me.

**Where is my assumption about the internal structure of datetime wrong?** How can I see this in the code?

(I guess this might differ between Python implementations - if so, please focus on cPython)

Comment: Mind you that `print(sys.getsizeof(d.year)) ;
print(sys.getsizeof(d.month)) ;
print(sys.getsizeof(d.day)) ;
print(sys.getsizeof(d.hour)) ;
print(sys.getsizeof(d.minute))  ;
print(sys.getsizeof(d.second)) ;
print(sys.getsizeof(d.microsecond))` prints `28` seven times, and `28 * 7` is `196`

Comment: note that you are counting _bits_ (2 int16_ts = 2*16) and not bytes (int16_t = 2 bytes). bytewise, this is 10 bytes. but python objects have overhead and the minimum size seems to be at least 28 bytes, sometimes higher depending on the object. i haven't done as much investigation there though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing a key part of the picture: the actual datetime struct definitions, which lie in [`Include/datetime.h`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.0/Include/datetime.h). There are also important comments in there. Here are some key excerpts:

```c
/* Fields are packed into successive bytes, each viewed as unsigned and
 * big-endian, unless otherwise noted:
 *
 * byte offset
 *  0           year     2 bytes, 1-9999
 *  2           month    1 byte, 1-12
 *  3           day      1 byte, 1-31
 *  4           hour     1 byte, 0-23
 *  5           minute   1 byte, 0-59
 *  6           second   1 byte, 0-59
 *  7           usecond  3 bytes, 0-999999
 * 10
 */

...

/* # of bytes for year, month, day, hour, minute, second, and usecond. */
#define _PyDateTime_DATETIME_DATASIZE 10

...

/* The datetime and time types have hashcodes, and an optional tzinfo member,
 * present if and only if hastzinfo is true.
 */
#define _PyTZINFO_HEAD          \
    PyObject_HEAD               \
    Py_hash_t hashcode;         \
    char hastzinfo;             /* boolean flag */

...

/* All datetime objects are of PyDateTime_DateTimeType, but that can be
 * allocated in two ways too, just like for time objects above.  In addition,
 * the plain date type is a base class for datetime, so it must also have
 * a hastzinfo member (although it's unused there).
 */

...

#define _PyDateTime_DATETIMEHEAD        \
    _PyTZINFO_HEAD                      \
    unsigned char data[_PyDateTime_DATETIME_DATASIZE];

typedef struct
{
    _PyDateTime_DATETIMEHEAD
} _PyDateTime_BaseDateTime;     /* hastzinfo false */

typedef struct
{
    _PyDateTime_DATETIMEHEAD
    unsigned char fold;
    PyObject *tzinfo;
} PyDateTime_DateTime;          /* hastzinfo true */
```

Additionally, note the following [lines](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.0/Modules/_datetimemodule.c#L5994) in `Modules/_datetimemodule.c`:

```c
static PyTypeObject PyDateTime_DateTimeType = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL, 0)
    "datetime.datetime",                        /* tp_name */
    sizeof(PyDateTime_DateTime),                /* tp_basicsize */
```

That `tp_basicsize` line says `sizeof(PyDateTime_DateTime)`, not `sizeof(_PyDateTime_BaseDateTime)`, and the type doesn't implement any special `__sizeof__` handling. That means the `datetime.datetime` type reports its instance size as the size of a time-zone aware datetime, even for unaware instances.

The 48-byte count you're seeing breaks down as follows:

- 8-byte refcount
- 8-byte type pointer
- 8-byte cached hash
- 1-byte "hastzinfo" flag
- 10-byte manually packed `unsigned char[10]` containing datetime data
- 1-byte "fold" flag ([DST-related](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fold))
- 4-byte padding, to align the tzinfo pointer
- 8-byte tzinfo pointer

This is true even though the actual memory layout of your unaware instance doesn't have a fold flag or tzinfo pointer.

This is, of course, all implementation details. It may be different on a different Python implementation, or a different CPython version, or a 32-bit CPython build, or a CPython debug build (there's extra stuff in the PyObject_HEAD when CPython is compiled with Py_TRACE_REFS defined).

Comment: Is `usecond: 3 byte` maybe a typo? Which type has 3 bytes? I've only seen some with 2 and some with 4 byte.

Comment: @MartinThoma: The bytes of the datetime data are manually packed in a `char[10]`, so there doesn't need to be a 3-byte type.