# How to convert datetime format using Pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime

I'a m reading a csv file with Pandas. In the file there is a column with dates in **dd/mm/yyyy** format.

```
def load_csv():   
    mydateparser = lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x, "%d/%m/%Y")
    return pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', delimiter=';', parse_dates=['data'], date_parser=mydateparser)
```

Using this parser the column 'data' type becomes **data         datetime64[ns]**, but the format is changed to **yyyy-mm-dd**.

I need the the column 'data' type to be **datetime64[ns]** and formated as **dd/mm/yyyy**.

How can it be done?

Regards,
Elio Fernandes

Comment: `yyyy-mm-dd` is the default *display* format. The underlying data type is Timestamp (this may showup as `datetime64`). It's not worth your effort to change the format during processing. When it comes time for final presentation (output, plotting, etc.), convert it with `.style` or `dt.strftime`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date is not stored in `yyyy-mm-dd` format or `dd/mm/yyyy` format. It's stored in **datetime** format. Python by default chooses to shows it in `yyyy-mm-dd` format. But don't get it wrong, it still is stored in datetime format.
You will get a better idea if you add time to data and then try to display it.
The way to achieve what you wish is by changing date to string right before displaying, so as, it remains datetime in dataframe but you get the specified string format when you display.
The following uses **Series.strftime()** to change to string. Documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html).

```
df['data'].strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

or
The following uses **datetime.strftime()** to change to string. Documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime).

```
df['data'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

For further reference check out [strftime-and-strptime-behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

This question will be of great help to understand how datetime is stored in python:
[How does Python store datetime internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52357460/how-does-python-store-datetime-internally)