# How to convert the format all the values in a date-time array?

Tags: python

This is my data :

```
dates = np.arange("2018-01-01", "2021-12-31", dtype="datetime64[D]")
```

I now want to convert from :
"2018-01-01" -> "Jan-01-2018"  ["Monthname-day-year"] format

How to i do this ?
Is it possible to initialize this in the way we want to convert ?
Can i use something like:

```
for i in dates:
   i =  i.replace(i.month,i.strftime("%b"))
```

Comment: I did but i understand that the input is not a string, a date-time array.

Comment: You understand that the array contains datetimes, but you don't seem to understand what that means. Datetimes are not stored in a particular "format". Internally, they're just numbers representing the time relative to some starting point (often the Unix epoch). It's not meaningful to convert a datetime object from one string format to another because they're not in a string format to begin with.

Comment: Ok, is it possible to initialize them in this way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
from datetime import datetime

dates = np.arange("2018-01-01", "2021-12-31", dtype="datetime64[D]")
result_dates = []
for date in dates.astype(datetime):
    result_dates.append(date.strftime("%b-%d-%Y"))
```

But you will need to convert result dates as shown in the code

Answer (score 1):

I feel compelled to elaborate on Silvio Mayolo's very relevant but ostensibly ignored comment above. Python stores a timestamp as structure (see [How does Python store datetime internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52357460/how-does-python-store-datetime-internally) for more information) Hence, the DateTime does not as such have a 'format'. A format only becomes necessary when you want to print the date because you must first convert the timestamp to a string. Thus, you do NOT need to initialise any format. You only need to declare a format when the time comes to print the timestamp.
While you CAN store the date as a string in your dataframe index in a specific format, you CANNOT perform time related functions on it without first converting the string back to a time variable. ie current_time.hour will return an integer with the current hour if current_time is a datetime variable but will crash if it is a string formatted as a timestamp (such as "2023-01-15 17:23").
This is important to understand, because eventually you will need to manipulate the variables and need to understand whether you are working with a time or a string.

Comment: I understand but i need to improve the readability in the graph, I have seen multiple times where the graphs have names of months instead of number ,i'm just trying to replicate the same. What would my alternative be ?

Comment: I would suggest having an index with DateTime data in it and then create an additional column or perhaps a temporary list created just before showing the graph with the string representation of the datetimes. You could even create a method that takes the dateseries index as a parameter to do this on demand. A simple list comprehension statement would suffice def DatesToStrings(date_series): return [date_series[i].strftime("%b-%d-%Y") for i in date_series]

Comment: Got it... I did the same ,thanks for the help.